# How to create a bootable USB stick that really works?

Tags: live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I would be very grateful if someone could help to create a bootable USB stick that really works. Instead of booting I get the following error message:

```
Gfx.c32: not a COM32R image
boot:
```

I'm using the built-in Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 14.04. As the USB device I'm using an empty 8GB USB flash drive. The ISO image that I'm trying to install is Ubuntu 18.04.

I followed the instructions of the Startup Disk Creator app. It automatically chose the image and the USB device. After some time I got the message `Installation complete`.

The problem is that when I set the USB device as the first bootable device I get the message indicated above at the beginning of this post.

PS: I have looked up the answers to an equivalent question, but they didn't work for me. Is there a new version of Startup Disk Creator which has fixed bug 1325801?

Comment: Did you verify the downloaded image (ISO) was valid?  ie. md5sum it?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Comment: Could it be that your processor is 32bit? So you would have to choose the 32bit version of Ubuntu (probably under alternative downloads).

Comment: If you can't get a 32-bit ISO image switch to a more lightweight flavor of Ubuntu that still has a 32-bit ISO image available.

Comment: @Richardgw What you have discovered is known [bug 1325801](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1325801). See @ sudodus [comment on it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1325801/comments/199) and his answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator in 14.04 LTS is buggy, and you are affected by a known bug, that is squashed by re-writing the Startup Disk Creator (from an extracting tool) to a robust cloning tool in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (and newer versions).

I suggest that you use another tool, for example mkusb according to the following links.

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

If you run standard Ubuntu *live*, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
```

The following links explain what is happening, when you create a USB boot drive, and describe some tools.

[Having trouble booting from flash drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965928/having-trouble-booting-from-flash-drive/965960#965960)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb)

Comment: Thank you sudodus your answer is the best and has given me the solution, I will use the mkusb tool